# NFC app crashing on enableForegroundDispatch

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am trying to get NFC foreground dispatch to work in my app using the tutorials
[here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-nfc-tags-with-android--mobile-17278) and [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/03/nfc-in-android-ndef.html). From what I can deduce all other functions seem to be working a it is just the NFC forground dispatch system that isn't working.

In my onCreate, I check NFC exists and initialise pending Intents and filters and get the NFC adapter:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Set some stuff
    mTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mButt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    //mNfcAd = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    //Init elsewhere
    getAdapter();

    //Hide button until its needed
    mButt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //Make sure NFC actually exists.....
    if (mNfcAd == null) {
        //Not going to work without NFC
        Toast.makeText(this, "This device does not support NFC\nGet used to the pen and paper for now :/", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    Intent nfcIntent = new Intent(this, getClass());
    nfcIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    nfcPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, nfcIntent, 0);

    IntentFilter tagIntentFilter =
            new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    try {
        tagIntentFilter.addDataType("text/plain");
        intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[]{tagIntentFilter};
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Init the prefs
    initPrefs();

}

public void initPrefs() {
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
}

private NfcAdapter getAdapter(){
    if(mNfcAd ==null){
        NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) getSystemService(NFC_SERVICE);
        mNfcAd = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
    }
    return mNfcAd;
}
```

I then go on to check NFC is enabled (if not display a button that shows NFC settings) as well as checking if the app is in its first run. At the end of onResume(), I (attempt to) enable Foreground Dispatch for the adapter.

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //Define the mButt action
    mButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS);
            dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(dialogIntent);
        }
    });
            //If NFC exists, check if its turned on
    if (!mNfcAd.isEnabled()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have NFC, but you haven't enabled it...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mTV.setText("NFC not enabled");
        mButt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    //Check if first run
    if (prefs.getInt("firstTime", 1) == 1 ||
            prefs.getString("fullName", null) == null ||
            prefs.getString("house", null) == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, First_Run.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        prefs.edit().putInt("firstTime", 0);
        prefs.edit().putString("fullName", getIntent().getExtras().getString("fullName"));
        prefs.edit().putString("house", getIntent().getExtras().getString("house"));
        prefs.edit().apply();
    }
    getAdapter().enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent, intentFiltersArray, null);
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}
```

The error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.nfc.NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(android.app.Activity, android.app.PendingIntent, android.content.IntentFilter[], java.lang.String[][])' on a null object reference
```

However, all the arguments seem to be initialised;
It is being called in onResume, so the activity context is created;
nfcPendingIntent and intentFiltersArray are initialised in onCreate;
I do not have a techlist so I use null as the final argument;
The adapter itself is initialised in getAdapter.

I am currently combing through other tutorials to see the different methods that can be used, however I would really like to get this fixed.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

<application
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".First_Run"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_first__run">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: did you try to use a empty intentFilter[] instead of null?

Comment: I assume you meant an empty String[][] instead of null. I tried that: `private static final String[][] EMPTY_ARRAY = new String[0][0];` and then `getAdapter().enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent, intentFiltersArray, EMPTY_ARRAY);`
  Unfortunately none of this worked and gave the error: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Null should be fine as a wildcard. Did you check whether you have a valid NFCAdapter object?

Comment: Just checked using this in my getAdapter():
`if(mNfcAd != null){
            return mNfcAd;
        }else{
            throw new IllegalStateException("NFC adapter has come out null");
        }`
It turns out that the adapter is null coming out of the getAdpater method, however I'm not sure why? 
I have followed the tutorial code for that section.

Comment: Do you use `getAdapter()` or `mNfcAd` anywhere else in your code too? Is there any code in your `onResume` method that you did not reveal in the above question?

Comment: I don't think I used it anywhere else, definitely not outside the class. I have since rewritten the whole class and it seems to be working. I'm still not sure what the problem was.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating your NfcAdapter object like below.

```
NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
```

Comment: This was the way I initialised it initially (It's still commented out somewhere in onCreate) however that didn't work either. I found another way of doing it (the one I'm using right now) and that gives the same error

Comment: Why don't you use mNfcAd.enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent, intentFiltersArray, null), instead of invoking getAdapter() again?

Comment: Just tried it, gives same result.  Doesn't that return the same object?